# What is the glyph origin of 克?

Tags: etymology, glyph-origin

I've looked around and one place says it's from the skin of an animal, another one says it's an axe striking a beast and another one says it's a battle helmet with an animal skin.

So what's the story behind it and it's relation to the meaning today?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<sub>Dislcaimer: The interpretations of the glyph forms and OC reconstructions are my personal opinion. *Professional opinions* state that this character is still open for interpretation.</sub>

<kbd>商
甲
[image]
甲1249
合集31219</kbd><kbd>西周
金
[image]
大克鼎
集成2836</kbd><kbd>春秋
金
[image]
公克敦
集成4641</kbd><kbd>今
楷
[image]</kbd>

I guess you can view「克」(Baxter-Sagart OC: **/*kʰˤək/**, *to achieve victory over/subdue/defeat an opponent in a military confrontation*), as being a merger between semantic「由」(*battle helmet*, now written as「冑」) and reduced phonetic「革」(**/*kˤrək/**). The graphically reduced「革」looks like「⿱廿尸」or「⿱口尸」(*picture of animal skin and horns*).

> Specifically, the bottom part of「由」is merged with the top part of the reduced「革」.

For reference:

- 「由」

  <kbd>商
  甲
  [image]
  甲2123
  合集557</kbd><kbd>戰國・楚
  簡帛
  [image]
  六德・19
  郭店楚簡</kbd><kbd>今
  楷
  [image]</kbd>
- 「皮」(*skinning an animal*)

  <kbd>西周
  金
  [image]
  九年衛鼎
  集成2831</kbd><kbd>秦
  簡
  [image]
  秦律十八7
  睡虎地秦簡</kbd><kbd>西漢
  隸
  [image]
  孫臏・220
  銀雀山漢簡</kbd>
  <kbd>今
  楷
  [image]</kbd>
- 「革」(*picture of flattened animal skin*). Roughly speaking,「⿱廿尸」or「⿱口尸」is「革」folded in half along the animal's spine.

  <kbd>商
  甲
  [image]
  花東474</kbd>
  　<kbd>西周
  金
  [image]
  康鼎
  集成2786</kbd><kbd>戰國・楚
  簡帛
  [image]
  遣策
  天星觀楚簡</kbd><kbd>秦
  簡
  [image]
  秦律雜抄16
  睡虎地秦簡</kbd><kbd>今
  楷
  [image]</kbd>

---

Comment: That's what I miss about the Outlier Dictionary sometimes. What you did was corroborating the ideas. The dictionary saying "it's a helmet with an animal skin" was not enough. You just drew every single part and now I'm totally convinced that it really is (even if it's wrong) a helmet fused with the skin. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

*Outlier* writes:

> 克 depicts a battle helmet (now written 古) and an animal skin (now written 儿). It was used in bronze inscriptions to mean “to defeat.”

Their reference is:

> 季旭昇，2004《說文新證》，台北：藝文印書館印行，2014年9月二版。p. 237

And they also give the ancient form of the character:

> [image]

Comment: Yeah, I have that dictionary. But sometimes I think the explanation is too shallow.